# record audio with exact timestamps

Tags: java, android, wear-os, audio-recording, audiorecord

I want to record raw audio on an android wear device, and exactly synchronize it with other sensor data, such as the accelerometer.
To record raw audio, I use [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord), but how can I determine the correct timestamp for any part of the audio stream?

The basic problem is that i get raw audio frames from the buffer, without information on how long those frames were in the buffer, how many frames were lost, etc.

So to get the frame data I call `AudioRecord.read()` in a loop, but how can I tell when a specific frame was recorded?

I can see three ways to determine a timestamp, and all of them seem wrong to me:

1. Get the current system time before or after calling [`AudioRecord.startRecording()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#startRecording()), by calling [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#elapsedRealtimeNanos()), and then calculate the time of each chunk based on the sample rate and frame size. But according to my tests there is a significant delay, until the recording actually starts. The time would also get out of sync whenever some frames are lost, e.g. when processing is stalled for a moment.
2. Get the current system time before or after [`AudioRecord.read()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int)). But that is probably not the time that this data was recorded, that could have happened a bit earlier. And if no data is available yet, read() will block and the timestamp taken before will be totally wrong.
3. [`AudioRecord.getTimestamp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#getTimestamp(android.media.AudioTimestamp,%20int)) gives the time of the frame that is currently recording. But that is not necessarily the frame that I am currently reading, I could be a couple frames behind, or I could have missed some frames. And according to initial tests, for some time after the start the timestamp is simply zero.

This would leave me with 6 probably wrong timestamps, shown in the code below. Is any of those even close to accurate?

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(...)

// timeBeforeStart =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
recorder.startRecording()
// timeAfterStart =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()

...

// timeBeforeRead =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
// recorder.getTimestamp(frameTimeBeforeRead, AudioTimestamp.TIMEBASE_BOOTTIME)
recorder.read(myArray, 0, mySize);
// recorder.getTimestamp(frameTimeAfterRead, AudioTimestamp.TIMEBASE_BOOTTIME)
// timeAfterRead =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
```

Which of these would be the most accurate way to determine the timestamp corresponding to the data in the byte array?

Is there a different method for retrieving raw audio data with accurate timestamps?

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) google repo can help you (check the class called AudioTimestampPoller)

Comment: If I interpret [AudioTimeStampPoller](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/6bfdf8f8f65a2d7a03d90e5e2e3bcdf80af31a94/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/audio/AudioTimestampPoller.java) right, it works work around some of the trickier behavior of getTimestamp(), but I still do not quite see how to correspond that timestamp with the frames which the current read() call returns from the buffer, and not the frames that are currently recording. So I do not quite see how it could be more accurate or even different than the current system time

Comment: to think out of the box - cant You just create high frequency blip or spike on the speaker that can be recorded along with the other audio and used to syncronize the frames afterward like a PLL ?

Comment: that might work, but then I would need to get accurate timestamps for audio output, with an unknown delay between queuing the audio and actual speaker, not sure if that is easier. the other option is of course hitting the watch, which will create correlated audio and accelerometer signals, but I was really hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @HugoRune have you managed to find an acceptable solution? I'm working on a similar idea now and would love to know if you found something 7 months later.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a correlated audio and accelerometer signal -
You might also throw flashlight, camera and speaker, etc. into the mix.

You need to test which actors & sensors have which delay and jitter, to find the optimal solution (without using an external device) to be able to correlate events in order to calculate the received audio delay and jitter.